# how to disable some keys/shortcuts in linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, shortcut

I'm writing a program that should disable certain key combinations (alt-tab, windows-tab, etc). in windows and osx I have achieved using hooks, but in linux I haven't found a way to do it. I would like to have a general solution, but if  works in gnome + ubuntu i'll be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `xmodmap`, but I'm not sure it is in line with the philosophy of the development of applications for GNU/Linux systems to modify from some application, without asking the user, a behaviour that users expect to be able to rely on at all times...

Comment: You're wrong in presuming that a user needs to be ***at all times*** in control of a software, machine. Take just for example unattended kiosk software.